# Rails4 - Bootstrap 3 my glyphicons render as empty boxes

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, twitter-bootstrap-3, glyphicons

I've lost my Glyphicons on my site and they are being replaced by empty boxes. I've seen a lot of issues with Bootstrap 3 and Glyphicons, but none of the fixes I've found are helping me so far. I've recently upgraded to gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.1.0.0'. I think my syntax is correct. Is there a path to teh Glyphicons that needs to be changed maybe?

Here are the three places I put Glyphicons:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="search" id="search">
  <div class="input-group-btn">
    <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
  </div>


<%= link_to pin, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } do %>
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
          Delete
<% end %>


<%= link_to root_path do %>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the best thing to do, but I added this to my CSS:

```
@import url("//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-glyphicons.css")
```

They're back!

Answer (score 0):

You can also add this to your scss file.

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
```

Comment: Along the way I had tried that, but it didn't work. Hopefully it will help someone else though! Thanks